# How to erase all geofences fed into the google Geofence API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api-client, android-geofence

I added geofences to the Google Geofence API as in [that example](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html). from time to time I would like to erase those geofences (either one by one or all togehter), independent of their expiration time etc.

```
mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
    // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
    // geofence.
    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())

    .setCircularRegion(
            entry.getValue().latitude,
            entry.getValue().longitude,
            Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
    )
    .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
    .build());
```

**How do I erase those geofences fed into the google Geofence API by myself?**

Answer (score 3):

Call  [`removeGeofences(GoogleApiClient client, PedingIntent pendingIntent)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi#public-methods) to removes all geofences associated with the given pendingIntent.

Use [`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) rather than  [`FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT) when creating the pending intent, otherwise you will not get the same pending intent you provided to addGeofences(GoogleApiClient, List, PendingIntent) https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html#addGeofences(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest, android.app.PendingIntent)]and thus the removal operation will remove nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
Syntax: geofencingClient.removeGeofences(getPendingIntent());

Note : geofencingClient is an Object to which geofences were added and 
getPendingIntent() is function which you used earlier.
```

getPendingIntent() function looks like this:

```
public PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
        if (pendingIntent != null) {
            return pendingIntent;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2607, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return pendingIntent;
    }
// GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class (Change this wrt to your code)
```

Call this function when you want to remove geofences:

```
void remove(){
        geofencingClient.removeGeofences(getPendingIntent());
    }
```